# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx

Recently upgraded POI jar version from 3.17 to 5.1 and below code which was working in 3.x is now broken, ( jdk 1.8 )

Below are the set of Jar used
[image]

below is my stub:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class ReadExcelDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("D:\\TemporaryUploadContainer\\61C50E5C2395C7FB48499BCFDD797F15_QuickCartExample.xlsx"));
 
            //Workbook workbook1 = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            //Sheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(0);
                        
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
 
            //Iterate through each rows one by one
            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
            {
                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                //For each row, iterate through all the columns
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                 
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) 
                {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    //Check the cell type and format accordingly
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                    {
                        case NUMERIC:
                            System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                        case STRING:
                            System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "t");
                            break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
            file.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Below Error for** : `Workbook workbook1 = WorkbookFactory.create(file);`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.(ThemesTable.java:86)
> at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
> at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:661)
> at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:275)
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:296)
> at test.XLSXReaderWriterP21.readRecordsFromFile(XLSXReaderWriterP21.java:76)
> at test.XLSXReaderWriterP21.main(XLSXReaderWriterP21.java:57)

**Below Error for** : `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);`

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.(ThemesTable.java:86)
> at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
> at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:661)
> at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:275)
> at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.(XSSFWorkbook.java:296)
> at test.ReadExcelDemo.main(ReadExcelDemo.java:26)

Comment: Please do not mix POI jars of different versions - poi-ooxml-schemas 4.1.2 will not work with poi 5.x - poi-ooxml-lite is the v5.1 equivalent - I would suggest that you spend some time learning to use build tools like gradle so that you can take advantage of their dependency management features - eg https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-gradle-example

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem.
Try to remove ***poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar***, and add ***poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.1.jar***

Comment: Super! I was facing this error but switching the poi-ooxml-schemas for poi-ooxml-lite solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: This answer fixed this issue for me too, with POI version 5.2.3. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with Netbeans, when i try to use:

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
```

or

```
Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(inputFile);
```

I fixed the problem changing poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar for poi-ooxml-lite-5.2.2.jar

Answer (score 0):

I think you had only adjust to same version this poi conform this FAQ https://poi.apache.org/help/faq.html#faq-N10204

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after updating `org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml` and  `org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml` from version `4.1.2` to `5.2.2`.

That's because `com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:2.1.0` was bringing `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.` as a dependency.

So I've updated the outdated [`com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:2.1.0`](https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader) with its fork [`com.github.pjfanning:excel-streaming-reader:4.0.4`](https://github.com/pjfanning/excel-streaming-reader):

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.pjfanning</groupId>
    <artifactId>excel-streaming-reader</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey just had the same problem as you.
Got it resolved by adding the following dependencies.

`poi-4.1.2.jar poi-ooxml-4.1.2.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar xmlbeans-3.1.0.jar`

As the other comment has suggested, poi-jars should be the same version, else it won't work correctly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: by adding those dependencies, you are still mixing versions. so either use 4.1.2 or 5.1.0.