# Exception when using Apache POi with OOXML java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory

Tags: apache-poi, openxml

I upgraded to Apache PO 5.2.3 recently (using JDK 1.8) and I have the following exception when creating a new Workbook:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.readFrom(ThemesTable.java:119)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.model.ThemesTable.<init>(ThemesTable.java:87)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:61)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:661)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:165)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:260)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.createWorkbook(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:118)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbookFactory.create(XSSFWorkbookFactory.java:36)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.lambda$create$2(WorkbookFactory.java:224)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.wp(WorkbookFactory.java:329)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:224)
    at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
```

I have the following dependencies, and looking at this StackOverflow question: [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606327/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-factory), I thought I had the correct dependencies. My dependencies are:

[image]

The test code I am using is very simple:

```
  File file = new File("L://WRK/Java/designchecker/common/configfiles/Styleset.xlsx");
  try {
     Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(file));
  } catch (Exception ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
```

I am sure that some of my version are incorrect, but I don't know which. Can somebody point to me where is my library version mismatch?

Comment: You only need to add `org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml` dependency. This includes all necessary transitive dependencies. The `poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar` definitely should not be there. `ooxml-schemas` is most probably not necessary as well

Comment: you must remove ooxml-schemas 1.4.jar  and poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar - you can't just throw random jars onto your classpath - these question has also been asked before - eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71380469/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-factory-question/71380678#71380678

Comment: I looked at this other question but I did not understand that when I read it. That's the reason why I created another question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As PJ. Fanning wrote, I need to remove these two libraries:

- ooxml-schemas 1.4.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-4.1.2.jar

When I do this, the exception disappear.